# Mailkit is sending emails with the incorrect from address

Tags: c#, mailkit

I've written a mail method and I'm setting the from email address but when the customer receives it, it's the same as the username that is used to authenticate the email.

I've tried to set the email right before the send and it still comes out wrong:

[image]

When I check the message, as shown above, the from is correct but the customer receives it from the username field instead.

```
public static EmailResults SendEmail(EmailSettings emailSettings)
{
  var emailResults = new EmailResults();

  try
  {
    // using mimekit that the msdn smtpclient webpage suggested using
    // http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Introduction.htm

    if (emailSettings.TestModeEnabled)
    {
      emailResults.IsSuccessful = true;
      emailResults.Message = "SendEmail disabled due to TestModeEnabled being set to true.";
      return emailResults;
    }

    // use the mimemessage to create the message to send
    var message = new MimeMessage();

    message.From.Add(emailSettings.FromEmail);
    message.Subject = emailSettings.EmailSubject;

    // to email has the option for multiple emails to be sent to
    // loop through them and add them all to the message
    foreach (var mailboxAddress in emailSettings.ToEmail)
    {
      message.To.Add(mailboxAddress);
    }

    // attach file if present
    var builder = new BodyBuilder();
    if (emailSettings.FileAttachments != null)
    {
      foreach (var file in emailSettings.FileAttachments)
      {
        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
          builder.Attachments.Add(file);
        }
      }
    }

    builder.HtmlBody = emailSettings.EmailBody;
    message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();

    //// http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Creating-Messages.htm
    //// A TextPart is a leaf-node MIME part with a text media-type. The first argument to the
    //// TextPart constructor specifies the media-subtype, in this case, plain. Another media
    //// subtype you are probably familiar with is the html subtype. Some other examples
    //// include enriched, rtf, and xml.
    //message.Body = new TextPart("html")
    //{
    //  Text = emailSettings.EmailBody
    //};

    // bcc has the option for multiple emails to be sent to
    // loop through them and add them all to the message
    if (emailSettings.BccEmail != null)
    {
      foreach (var mailboxAddress in emailSettings.BccEmail)
      {
        message.Bcc.Add(mailboxAddress);
      }
    }

    // *************** SEND EMAIL *******************
    var client = emailSettings.EnableSmtpLog ? new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient(new ProtocolLogger(GlobalVariables.SmptpLogFile)) : new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient();

    using (client)
    {
      if (emailSettings.SmtpServer.Contains("gmail.com"))
      {
        // Note: since we don't have an OAuth2 token, disable
        // the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.
        client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
      }

      client.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;

      //accept all SSL certificates
      client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;

      // client.Connect(emailSettings.SmtpServer, emailSettings.SmtpPort, emailSettings.IsSslEnabled);
      client.Connect(emailSettings.SmtpServer, emailSettings.SmtpPort, emailSettings.AuthType);

      if (emailSettings.IsAuthenticationRequired)
      {
        // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
        client.Authenticate(emailSettings.SmtpUsername, emailSettings.SmtpPassword);
      }

      if (emailSettings.TimeOut == 0) emailSettings.TimeOut = 10;
      client.Timeout = emailSettings.TimeOut * 1000;

      //message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("someone@somewhere.net"));

      client.Send(message);
      client.Disconnect(true);
    }

    // if we reached this far, then the email was sent successfully
    emailResults.Message = "Successfully sent.";
    emailResults.IsSuccessful = true;
    return emailResults;

  }

  catch (AuthenticationException e)
  {
    Logging.LogException("SmtpClient.SendEmail", "Error attempting to send email.", e);
    emailResults.IsSuccessful = false;
    emailResults.Message = "Invalid username or password.";
    return emailResults;
  }

  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Logging.LogException("SmtpClient.SendEmail", "Error attempting to send email.", e);
    emailResults.IsSuccessful = false;

    if (e.Message.Contains("error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection"))
    {
      emailResults.Message = "An error occurred while attempting to establish a secure connection.\r\n\r\nPlease check your email settings.";
    }
    else
    {
      emailResults.Message = e.Message;
    }

    return emailResults;
  }
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who runs in to this again...

This particular issue is specific to Gmail. I'm not sure if other email hosts do the same.

If you are setting the from email address to "person1@email.com" but authenticating with "person2@gmail.com", Gmail will override the from email address with the authentication email address. You have no control over this.

Comment: I think you can accept your own answer and I can confirm that your answer is correct (I actually came here to provide the same answer you found yourself).

Comment: Yeah, that was a hard one to find. I thought Mailkit had a bug. It won't let me upvote it until tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Gmail account, into settings, and add the alias address in the "Send Mail As" section.  The outgoing email should now display with the alias address rather than the authenticating address.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).